# Matching cell contents in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Excel sheets.

Sheet1 has 3 columns

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
```

Sheet2 has 3 columns also!

```
Column(A) Column(B) Column(C)
```

I want to match `Column1` with `Column(A)`. If `Column1=Column(A)` then `Column(B) & Column(C)` will be automatically insert on Sheet1 after `Column3`. That means 2 new columns will be added to `Sheet1` taken from `Sheet2`

Any formula/VBA for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use VLOOKUP.

It's used this way:

```
VLOOKUP(value to search for, range to search in, column to return, exact match (0) or not (1))
```

In your case that would look something like this, in cell D2 for example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$C$1000, 2, 0)
```

In cell E2:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!$A$2:$C$1000, 3, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Plz solve my little confusion. As per your formula D2 & E2 will be on sheet1 or sheet2?? Thanks again!

Comment: The formula returns data so you want to have them on your first sheet if this is where you want to return data.

Comment: Thanks! Yes mistake was mine! Now its solved! Thanks for your help :)